# Jupyter требует пароль jovyan

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

При вводе команды !sudo apt-get update Jupyter-notebook отвечает мне "sudo password for jovyan, но никакого окна ввода пароля и так далее нет, подскажите пожалуйста куда вообще вводить этот пароль или как убрать это требование ввода пароля.

Answer (score 0):

Если это у вас окно консоли, то просто надо ввести ваш пароль в терминале

Вводится он так - просто набираете пароль и нажимаете Enter

При это вы не увидите свой пароль, но вам надо его указать и нажать Enter